# Enable Bin logging throw error in Ubuntu 18.04 for MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I was trying to do `mysqldump` but I got error of Enable Bin logging

As far documentation I need to enable `log-bin`

So I opened sudo gedit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

and remove `#` from the front of log_bin

```
log_bin     = /var/log/mysql/bin.log
```

Now restart the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I checked by `systemctl status mysql.service`

It gave me

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-21 16:07:50 IST; 38s ago
  Process: 8612 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9463 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8614 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 21 16:07:50 frrrr-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution

We need to uncomment(remove `'#'`) from server-id, and other as below

```
server-id       = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

Then restart mysql service and it will work..